# LUKS encrypted drive will not accept password

Tags: fedora, disk-encryption, luks

I have a brand new 4TB drive that I installed and encrypted using this tutorial:

https://www.tecmint.com/encrypt-drives-using-luks-in-fedora-linux/

System is a fresh install of Fedora 30.

When I get done, the drive shows up in my Fedora sidebar, and when I click it asks for a password. I am 200% sure I typed the password in correctly, in fact it accepted it when I got to the `mkfs` step, but now when I try to unlock it, it won't accept the password.

I went through this three times, and two separate brand new drives, reformatting them each time, and it never allows me to unencrypt them, is there a reason?

The error is:

> Error unlocking /dev/sdb: Failed to activate device: File exists

Here's the output of
`sudo cryptsetup --debug luksOpen /dev/sda /dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79`:

> cryptsetup 2.2.0 processing "cryptsetup --debug luksOpen /dev/sda /dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79"
>   Running command open.
>   Locking memory.
>   Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
>   Unblocking interruption on signal.
>   Allocating context for crypt device /dev/sda.
>   Trying to open and read device /dev/sda with direct-io.
>   Initialising device-mapper backend library.
>   Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/sda.
>   Crypto backend (OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.2.0.
>   Detected kernel Linux 5.2.9-200.fc30.x86_64 x86_64.
>   Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
>   Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sda.
>   Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:0
>   Verifying lock handle for /dev/sda.
>   Device /dev/sda READ lock taken.
>   Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
>   Opening locked device /dev/sda
>   Veryfing locked device handle (bdev)
>   LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
>   Checksum:3acf534054a6b4850a43fe7e760949c422748a1bc7f7de49b48cfda3911d751c (on-disk)
>   Checksum:3acf534054a6b4850a43fe7e760949c422748a1bc7f7de49b48cfda3911d751c (in-memory)
>   Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
>   Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sda
>   LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
>   Checksum:62399b5cb65dff96cef8c2bde94d100e3c9f1a88cef7bdd08f47a11df90db2bc (on-disk)
>   Checksum:62399b5cb65dff96cef8c2bde94d100e3c9f1a88cef7bdd08f47a11df90db2bc (in-memory)
>   Device size 4000787030016, offset 16777216.
>   Device /dev/sda READ lock released.
>   PBKDF argon2i, time_ms 2000 (iterations 0), max_memory_kb 1048576, parallel_threads 4.
>   Activating volume /dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79 using token -1.
>   Interactive passphrase entry requested.
>   Enter passphrase for /dev/sda:
>   Activating volume /dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79 [keyslot -1] using passphrase.
>   dm version   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
>   dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
>   Detected dm-ioctl version 4.40.0.
>   Detected dm-crypt version 1.18.1.
>   Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
>   dm status luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
>   Device /dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79 already exists.
>   Releasing crypt device /dev/sda context.
>   Releasing device-mapper backend.
>   Closing read only fd for /dev/sda.
>   Unlocking memory.
>   Command failed with code -5 (device already exists or device is busy).

Comment: Does `/dev/mapper/luks-2d7e94ef-dc79-40e2-b97b-057b1d182d79` exist before you run `cryptsetup`?

Comment: I get that error after I encrypt the drive and format it, and then run sudo cryptsetup --debug luksOpen